# More than one IViewComponentResult method in ViewComponent Class

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

Is it possible to access more than one IViewComponentResult method in a single ViewComponent Class? I seem to be able to create more then one method with each referencing their own View, but I have been unable to find a way to reference the individual methods within the class from a razor view.

```
public class PageHeaderViewComponent: ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Header(LayoutModel layoutModel)
    {
        return View("Header", layoutModel);
    }

    public IViewComponentResult PageHeaderUpper(LayoutModel layoutModel)
    {
        return View("PageHeaderUpper", layoutModel);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can pass a parameter to Invoke method to conditionally return different view:

```
public class PageHeaderViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke(LayoutModel layoutModel,string name)
    {
        if(name=="header")
        {
            return View("Header", layoutModel);
        }
        else
        {
            return View("PageHeaderUpper", layoutModel);
        }
    }
}
```

You can invoke the view components like below in main view:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync(typeof(PageHeaderViewComponent), new { LayoutModel= new LayoutModel() , name = "header" })
@await Component.InvokeAsync(typeof(PageHeaderViewComponent), new { LayoutModel= new LayoutModel() , name = "aaa" })
```

View Components location:

[image]

Besides, you can also use the property in LayoutModel as the condition.